# display picutre in grid layout djang-admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

first, I am having issues with displaying thumbnails in Django-admin, I tried the code below but it is not working it seems,

```
class Pictures(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=True)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organisation,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return f"{self}"


    @mark_safe
    def image_img(self):
        if self.image:
            return format_html('<img src="{0}" style="width: 60px; height:65px;" />'.format(self.image.url))
        else:
            return format_html('<img src="" alt={0} style="width: 60px; height:65px;" />'.format("noimagefound"))
            
    image_img.short_description = 'Image'
    image_img.allow_tags = True



class PicturesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('image', 'date_added','image_img')
    autocomplete_fields = ['organization']

    list_display_links = ('date_added',)
```

I also want to display **these thumbnails in *the grid layout***, how can I achieve that any simple approach

[image]

Comment: you do not need __unicode__ if you're using python3, use __str__ instead.

Comment: and also for imageField null=True is scary instead use just blank=True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

models.py

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
class Pictures(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True,upload_to="pictures/")
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organisation,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.pk}"


    def image_img(self):
        if self.image:
            return mark_safe('<img src="%s" style="width: 60px; height:65px;" />' % self.image.url )
        else:
            return mark_safe('<img src="" alt="%s" style="width: 60px; height:65px;" />' % "noimagefound")
            
    image_img.short_description = 'Image'
```

Comment: i changed it to mark safe but still the same

Comment: @AtifShafi i edited my answer. first add blank=True,and upload_to  and python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate.and i changed a little bit my image_img.

Comment: i made all the changes still showing the same

Comment: @AtifShafi then you have to upload new images because you already changed the path of images when using upload_to="pictures/".upload new images and it should work.

Comment: @AtifShafi do not forget to import mark_safe and replace "{}" with "%s" like what i did above.

Comment: @AtifShafi is it working ?

Comment: I am stuck, i have one more question about the layout down there , bolded that

Comment: @AtifShafi accept the answer if it helps you.if you have an other question please consider asking a new question separately.https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237786/discussion-between-atif-shafi-and-amadou-sow).

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the `format_html` part wrong

```py
    @mark_safe
    def image_img(self):
        if self.image:
            return format_html('<img src="{}" style="width: 60px; height:65px" />', self.image.url)
        else:
            return format_html('<img src="" alt="{}" style="width: 60px; height:65px" />', "noimagefound")
```

Comment: i will accept the answer as soon as , issue is fixed no issue